# jquery vars get to an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

i have a little problem with vars on event. So i have a plugin whitch called another plugin and i want to get a jquery element from called plugin to main plugin... like this.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.meRadioCheck = function(options, callback) {
        options = $.extend($.fn.meRadioCheck.defaults, options);
        var plugin = this;

        plugin.init = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                var $span = $('<span/>');
                var name = $this.attr('name');

                /* here some stuff... */

                /* check for Events */
                if (($._data(this, "events") == null)) {

                    /* Change Event an Element binden */
                    $this.bind("xonChange", function() {
                        options.CheckBox_onChange.call($this)
                     });

                    $this.on({
                        change: function() {
                            /* here some stuff... */

                            /* throw Change Event */
                            $this.trigger("xonChange");
                        },
                    });
                };
            });
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var name = $this.attr('name');

            if (options.checked != $this.prop('checked')) { $this.click(); } 
            if (options.disabled) { $this.prop('disabled', true) } else { $this.prop('disabled', false) }
        });
    };

    // Standard-Optionen für das Plugin
    $.fn.meRadioCheck.defaults = {
        'checked':  false,                                  /* This Checkbox or Radio Button is checked */
        'debug':    false,                                  /* Debug Modus für das Plugin ein od. ausschalten */
        'disabled': false,                                  /* This Checkbox or Radio Button is disabled */

        'CheckBox_onChange': function(el) {},
        'RadioButton_onChange': function(el) {}
    }
})(jQuery);



(function($) {
    $.panel = function(options, callback) {

        $('input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').meRadioCheck({

            CheckBox_onChange: function(el) {
                /* some stuff here... */
                window.console.debug('panel:  ' + typeof(el) + ', onChange: ', [el])
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

i only get this in the console:   **panel:  undefined, onChange: [undefined]**

but i want to get the CheckBox or RadioButton. I hope someone can help me...

Thanks... and have a nice Weekend.

Comment: is `init()` ever called?

Comment: no, i call `init()` only once at the beginning like this... `$('input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').meRadioCheck().init();`

Comment: That goes against how jQuery plugins are typically designed and you should reconsider it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.meRadioCheck.defaults = {
        'debug':    false,             /* debug-mode for plugin */
        'checked':  false,             /* this checkbox or radio button is checked */
        'disabled': false,             /* this checkbox or radio button is disabled */
        'CheckBox_onChange': null,
        'RadioButton_onChange': null
    };
    $.fn.meRadioCheck = function(overrideOptions, callback) {
        var plugin = this,
            options = $.extend($.fn.meRadioCheck.defaults, overrideOptions);

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                name = $this.attr('name');

            if ( !$this.data().meRadioCheckInitDone ) {
                $this.on("change", function() {
                    if (typeof options.CheckBox_onChange === "function") {
                        options.CheckBox_onChange.call(this);
                    }
                }).data("meRadioCheckInitDone", true);
            }

            $this.prop('checked', !!options.checked);
            $this.prop('disabled', !!options.disabled);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Changes

- Gotten rid of `.init()`, it did not seem to serve any purpose.
- Used a `.data()` variable instead of calling an internal API function to check if initialization is through. Seems cleaner.
- Gotten rid of the custom `xonChange` event - listening to `change` directly will work just as well if all you do is call *another* function from there.
- Added a `typeof` check for the event callback.
- Setting `$this.prop()` unconditionally seems cleaner than the if-then-else you do.

On a more general note, you seem to implement some sort of data binding. Maybe looking into a data binding framework like knockout.js is worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not really what i want. I use this plugin 'meRadioCheck' for initialize the CheckBoxes and RadioButtons to set the Layout of them. (i use this often in other Projects). And now i want to throw the change event to the calling (main) plugin. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. First off, you don't throw events anywhere. You trigger them and whoever has set up an event listener will receive them. Apart from that, my code does the same thing as your code, so *"not really what i want"* can't be right.

Comment: Of course, your code do the same,... but the problem is, i won't change the code in the plugin `.meRadioCheck();`. This i use in some other projects for styling the Layout of CheckBoxes and RadioButtons. What i want the change event make available from outside.